# Taking screenshots/recordings of iPhone simulator without the gaps

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, video-capture, screen-capture

Is there a way to take a screenshot or video recording of the iPhone X/XS simulator without the gaps? I'm talking about the black gaps here:

[image]

I'm making an app promo using recordings from the simulator and having these gaps doesn't look good -- it makes for bad screenshots too.

If it helps any way, I'm using this command to record a video of the simulator:

`xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo myvideo.mov`

...which works perfectly except the video starts off with *no* gaps, then a second in the gaps show.

Comment: If you are recording the only video of simulator so there is a way to do this is a select simulator and go to windows menu and select "Show Device Bezels" I think it will resolve your problem.

Comment: @iOSTeam That removes the outline of the phone, but doesn't get rid of (or fill in, rather) the dark cutouts.

Comment: So I think the answer is no for that or else you can record video on the real device also and also one more comment is that is if there is no notch on the phone so how can anyone know it is the iPhone X/XS ?, You can go for iPhone 8 , And please check this option also : https://appetize.io/upload